# can`t send tweet with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, twitter

hi there i need some help with the following code ....
i`m using selenium with python to send tweets automatically :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/webDriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Phone, email or username']")
password= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='js-password-field']")
username.send_keys("xxxx")
password.send_keys("xxxx")

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']")
submit.click()
time.sleep(2.4)
autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '//*[@id="tweet-box-home-timeline"]/div'))).click
autotw1.send_keys("""testing """)  

time.sleep(5)
tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="add-tweet-button "]//following-sibling::button[contains(@class,"tweet-action")]')
tweet.click()
```

But It gave me error :

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

i think the error came from xpath cause of the twitter website new style !!

Comment: you should be aware that removing the content from your own question (once said question is answered), is **really** frowned upon and can/will be sanctioned as *vandalism*. Besides - it is still visible in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57945357/revisions) of your question. If there is a real, good reason why the information should be gone (e.g. accidently posting personal information, etc.) you should flag the Question so a moderator can clean it (including the history) for you.

Comment: @coode3r I don't understand why you want edit your question and my answer in same time, with a trial of change that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @frianH If they edited only your answer or their question I'd assume they made an honest accident/mistake (selecting stuff, then slipping on the space bar or something). Since they did it on both I can only imagine two reasons: Mindless vandalism (though I feel this is unlikely) or they want to pass the code as "their own work" (maybe for school or job) and tried to hide the fact that they actually got assistance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this locator:`By.CLASS_NAME, 'DraftEditor-root'`.

You must click on the element to bring up other elements to write the tweet, which is:`By.CLASS_NAME, 'public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root')`, and use `ActionChains` to send text.

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Try the bellow code:

```
#submit login
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']")
submit.click()

autotw1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'DraftEditor-root')))
autotw1.click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-root')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys('testing').perform()

sendTw = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Tweet')))
sendTw.click()
```